# what is the attribute of the moddifier that i need to change to make the corners rouned and the width a little smaller? jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-compose-textfield

my question is different from the suggested question that is similar because I am making the voting bar change in effect from the parameters of the voting percentage. therefore I need the left column to change dynamically in size and the right column to change dynamically in size therefore I find it difficult to implement with a Stroke object.

what is the attribute of the modifier that I need to change to make the corners round? and the width a little smaller of a Row() element

I am trying to make an android app with jetpack compose,
in the process of implementing the Voting bar which is the bar in the middle with the 2 colors of red and blue.
I can't find the correct attribute to modify so the corners of the bar will be rounded and make the width different from .fillMaxWidth() in the modifier so I ended up using it until I will find a solution.
if you have any insights :) thanks in advance ~!

Figma Design

[image]

implementation in android

[image]

my code

```
@Composable
fun VotingBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, leftyPercent: Int, rightyPercent: Int
) {
    var leftyPercentWeight: Float = (leftyPercent / 10).toFloat()
    var rightyPercentWeight: Float = (rightyPercent / 10).toFloat()
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black, CircleShape)
    ) {
        Column(
            // add rounded corners to the left side
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFFA60321))
                .height(50.dp)
                .weight(leftyPercentWeight)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

        ) {

        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFF03588C))
                .height(50.dp)
                .weight(rightyPercentWeight)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            // add rounded corners to the right side
        ) {}
    }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .background(Color.White),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    ) {
        Row {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(Color(0xFFA60321))
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Right $rightyPercent%", fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        }

        Row() {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(Color(0xFF03588C))
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Left $leftyPercent%", fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        }


    }

}
```

I followed the 5 steps tutorial at the leading developer's website but I fill still a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw rounded corner polygons in Jetpack Compose Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748987/how-to-draw-rounded-corner-polygons-in-jetpack-compose-canvas)

Comment: it is similar but it is not helping me because I will lose the dynamically size of the voting ? if not I cant think on a way to implement a stroke that is also moving ... also do you know about the witdh attribute how can I change the width of a row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the 2 `Row` in a `Column` applying a `padding` modifier (to avoid the full width) and an horizontalAlignment.
Then in the 1st `Row` apply a `clip` modifier to achieve the rounded shape.

Something like:

```
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(32.dp)

Column(
    Modifier.padding(16.dp),
    horizontalAlignment= Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(32.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
            .clip(shape)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Black, shape)
    ) {
        Column(
            // add rounded corners to the left side
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFFA60321))
                .weight(leftyPercentWeight)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

        ) {

        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xFF03588C))
                .weight(rightyPercentWeight)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            // add rounded corners to the right side
        ) {}
    } 
    //2nd Row

}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot helped me figure the missing idea!

Comment: hey! i now trying your solution and I don't see the colors until I am using .fillmaxHeight on the columns so I am editing your answer to fit the best solution for more people :)

Comment: i cant edit your answer so.. please add that attribute to modifiers of columbs