# how to make Parralel scroll in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I am makeing a profile screen in jetpack compose

***I want to make the Blue background behind the image scroll up when the image is scrolled up because it doesn't look good :)
This is what I need help with, see the gif to understand better.***

[image]

how can I achieve what I want, that the blue background will scroll up also?

I tried moving the background box around the code,
out of the column at the head
out of the column at the TopBar
out of the column at the ProfileSection

but it didn't work because the column rearrange the objects so that they are ontop of each other and I just want it from behind

source code

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.politi_cal.R


@Composable
fun CelebProfileScreen() {
     BlackBackgroundSquare()
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        LazyColumn(content = {
            item {

                TopBar()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
                ProfileSection(
                    name = "Amit Segal",
                    company = "N12 news channel",
                )

                // voting bar
                VotingBar(
                    leftyPercent = 10, rightyPercent = 90
                )
                // lazy column for more info

                MoreInfo("Amit Segal is a journalist and a news anchor. He is the host of the N12 news channel. He is a very popular journalist. Amit Yitzchak Segal[1] (born Biz in Nisan 5, 1982, April 10, 1982) is an Israeli journalist, radio and television personality. Serves as the political commentator of the news company and a political columnist in the \"Yediot Aharonot\" newspaper. One of the most influential journalists in Israel[2]. Presents Meet the Press on Channel 12 together with Ben Caspit.")


            }
        })


    }
}

@Composable
fun MoreInfo(information_param: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.padding(start = 26.dp, end = 26.dp)) {

        Text(
            text = "More information",
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Text(
            text = information_param,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
            maxLines = 10,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
        )


    }
}

@Composable
fun VotingBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, leftyPercent: Int, rightyPercent: Int
) {
    var leftyPercentWeight: Float = (leftyPercent / 10).toFloat()
    var rightyPercentWeight: Float = (rightyPercent / 10).toFloat()

    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(32.dp)
    Column(
        Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
                .clip(shape)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Black, shape)
        ) {
            Column(
                // add rounded corners to the left side
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color(0xFFA60321))
                    .weight(rightyPercentWeight)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {

            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color(0xFF03588C))
                    .fillMaxHeight(leftyPercentWeight)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                // add rounded corners to the right side
            ) {

            }
        }
        // second row
        // stack over flow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74619069/what-is-the-attribute-of-the-moddifier-that-i-need-to-change-to-make-the-corners?noredirect=1#comment131712293_74619069
        Column(
            Modifier.padding(start = 46.dp, end = 46.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.White),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            ) {
                Row {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(30.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .background(Color(0xFFA60321))
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "Right $rightyPercent%",
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                }

                Row() {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(30.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .background(Color(0xFF03588C))
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "Left $leftyPercent%", fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BlackBackgroundSquare() {
    Box(
        // modifier fill only half the screen
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
            // insert background color as hex
            .background(Color(0xFF2C3E50))
    )
}

@Composable
fun TopBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Profile",
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            color = Color.White
        )

    }

}


@Composable
fun ProfileSection(
    name: String, company: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        RoundImage(
            image = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile_pic), modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = name,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            color = Color.Black
        )
        Text(
            text = company,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            color = Color.Black
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun RoundImage(
    image: Painter, modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Image(
        painter = image,
        contentDescription = "Profile image",
        modifier = modifier
            .aspectRatio(1f, matchHeightConstraintsFirst = true)
            .border(
                width = 6.dp, color = Color.White, shape = CircleShape
            )
            .padding(3.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `LazyColumn`, if it contains only a single item, but `Box` is a simple component for placing components on top of each other, which could be used here for the item like this:

```
    item {
        Box {
            BlackBackgroundSquare()
            Column {
                TopBar()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
                ProfileSection(
                    name = "Amit Segal",
                    company = "N12 news channel",
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am a noob in jetpack compose I tried to do so and broke the code can you make the example please?

Answer (score 1):

Add a state to LazyColumn, then use state.firstVisibleItemIndex to detect when first item is not visible. Use a DisposableEffect to detect index by index to prevent lag. When first idx is consumed, hide your upper bar. Could use a viewmodel to save first index. Then show action bar if first item is visible again.

```
    DisposableEffect(key1 = listState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
    onDispose {              
    viewModel
    .setFirstVisibleItemIdx(listState.firstVisibleItemIndex)
     }
    }
```

On enter get the index from viewmodel and scroll. If no value, just show as normal.

```
          LaunchedEffect(viewModel.firstVisibleItemIdx) {
            listState.scrollToItem(viewModel.firstVisibleItemIdx.value ?: 0)
        }
```

Comment: I am a noob in jetpack compose and didn't understand your answer can you give more information and expand the example a bit

Comment: So that I will know how to implement tht

Comment: That thing you were saying