How to draw a hexagon with rounded corners on Android Canvas?
I want to make a hexagon with rounded corners, but I don't have any idea how to do it. I try it with different methods like: cubicTo, arcTo, etc.

My code to draw this
fun Path.customHexagon(radius: Float, size: Size) {
    val triangleHeight = (sqrt(3.0) * radius / 2)
    val centerX = size.width / 2
    val centerY = size.height / 2

    moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius)
    lineTo((centerX - triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY + radius/2)
    lineTo((centerX - triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY - radius/2)
    lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius)
    lineTo((centerX + triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY - radius/2)
    lineTo((centerX + triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY + radius/2)

    close()
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748987/how-to-draw-rounded-corner-polygons-in-jetpack-compose-canvas

Similar to this you can repeat it here for Jetpack Compose:
@Composable
fun Hexagon(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    ) {
        val size = 300f
        val trianglePath = Path().apply {
            val triangleHeight = (sqrt(3.0) * size / 2)
            val centerX = this@Canvas.size.width / 2
            val centerY = this@Canvas.size.height / 2

            moveTo(centerX, centerY + size)
            lineTo((centerX - triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY + size / 2)
            lineTo((centerX - triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY - size / 2)
            lineTo(centerX, centerY - size)
            lineTo((centerX + triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY - size / 2)
            lineTo((centerX + triangleHeight).toFloat(), centerY + size / 2)
            close()
        }

        drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
            canvas.drawOutline(
                outline = Outline.Generic(trianglePath),
                paint = Paint().apply {
                    color = Color.Black
                    pathEffect = PathEffect.cornerPathEffect(50f)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}



There is an androidx library graphics-shapes that does exactly that. As of today, it is still a release candidate though. You can create rounded hexagon simply like this:
val hexagon = RoundedPolygon(
  numVertices = 6,
  radius = 200f,
  rounding = CornerRounding(
    radius = 50f,
  )
).toPath()

library import:
implementation "androidx.graphics:graphics-shapes:1.0.0-rc01"

